# Transição reversa de slide, VUE JS

Tags: css3, css-transições, vue.js

Estou desenvolvendo uma single page aplication/app mobile, com VUE JS, quero efeito slide ao trocar de páginas, e já consigo fazer isso dessa maneira:

```
transition name="slide"
router-view
transition
```

Porém eu queria o efeito inverso do slide quando o usuário voltar a página, ou seja, quando o usuário abrir uma nova página, a página virá da direita, quando votar, a página virá da esquerda.

Tem um plugin para vue router, chamado vue-router-transition ([Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-router-transition)) mas não funciona, está desatualizado, da erros, só funciona com  versões muito antigas do VUE.

Também tem tutorial de como fazer transições dinâmicas, mas só funciona quando for rotas filhas, como `site.com/rota1/rota2/rota3`, o que não é o meu caso: `https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/transitions.html`

Pensei na seguinte lógica, no `before.each.router`, definir a classe da transição, (`slide-left` ou `slide-right`) dependendo se o usuário clicou em algum botão de *Go back*, o problema é que eu não sei aplicar essa lógica no código, teria que passar o valor de uma variável que esta no main.js para o app.vue e eu não sei como fazer isso...

Comment: Não entendi, o que é esse número?